# Swr and vercel keep data after deleting in production and display it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using Mysql -> Prisma hosted on Planet Scale, and NextJs hosted on Vercel.
I use SWR because is recommended by the NextJS, However in production everything is fine.

To fetch data, I created a separate file where after defining the fetcher and the get, put, delete functions...
In development, after deleting a record I get the rest of the records in an array, but in the production, I get the same array, even if the database have no more records...

This is the function where I fetch all the records.. I return all the fields, because I use is loading boolean to load the loader page.

```
//getCompletedQuotes
export const GetCompletedQuotesArray = () => {
    const { data: completedQuotes, isLoading: CompletedQuotesLoading, mutate: mutateCompletedQuotes } = 
    useSWR(`${baseURL}/get-completed-quotes`, fetcher);

    return { completedQuotes, CompletedQuotesLoading, mutateCompletedQuotes }
}
```

This is the delete function by Id. I use the fetch here, because if I try to implement the mutate function her I get all sort of errors. Firstly I fetch the rest of the quotes, and after the delete I return the remaining records.

````
//get all the quotes
export const getAllQuotes = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/get-quotes`, {method: 'GET'});
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('', error);        
    }
};



//delete the quotes and execute the getAllQuotes to return the remaining quotes
export const deleteQuoteById = async (quoteId: string) => {
    try {
        await fetch(`${baseURL}/delete-quote?id=${quoteId}`, { method: 'DELETE' });
        const allRemainingQuotes = await getAllQuotes();
        console.log(allRemainingQuotes);
        return allRemainingQuotes;
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('', error);        
    }
}
```;


I don't know where to look. I get no error in vercel console, no error in production browser console / network tab...
````

Comment: I even added multiple records in the table, but no change...